# Trying to float navigation images

Tags: html, css, image

I have tried everything I can think of and read lots of posts on here. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code, it's probably something silly knowing my luck.

Anyway, I am trying to put 4 navigation images in a line, which I've done before, and have them be fixed on the page. For some reason I'm having an issue. I've tried floating them and I just can't seem to get them all to fall in line, I've got two of them to float in a line, then some text links, then the next two break and float on their own.

Sorry if this is overly simple, I don't usually have issues like this.

For the record, I haven't "fixed" them yet, I wanted them to fall in line first.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="Container">
  <a style="float: left;" href="#">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FirstArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="FirstArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="68" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-158"
    />
  </a>

  <a style="float: left;" href="#">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="PreviousArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="50" height="50" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-161"
    />
  </a>

  <a href="#">1</a>  <a href="#">2</a>  <a href="#">3</a> 

  <a style="float: left;" href="#">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/NextArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="NextArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="50" height="50" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-160"
    />
  </a>

  <a style="float: left;" href="#">
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/LastArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet.png" alt="LastArrowsLikeACatPagenJewelryPentagramsSilverWiccanNecklaceBracelet" width="68" height="50" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-159"
    />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example visual of what you're trying to achieve? It seems to me like you just need to float the text links as well

Comment: It's a locally hosted file, your suggestion worked for making them fall into line(Thank you so much btw, I can't believe I didn't think of that)

Comment: Have you tried floating all of the `<a>` tags? Also you might want to think about using character symbols instead of images.

Comment: One more question, for some reason when I fix the div the images no longer float; what is going on here?

Comment: If I can't get this to do what I want it to, I might just switch to character symbols. This just looks nicer with my layout.

Answer (score 0):

The first item has WP class `aligncenter`, which works against what you want to achieve.

After the second one, there are indeed three text links, which are inline, which is also against what you want to achieve.

Comment: I totally didn't notice that, darn WP image placer